# My iPhone was stolen

Tags: icloud, iphone, accounts, find-my-iphone, secure-erase

My iPhone6 was stolen
and the thief was Erased my id from Icloud
In my country I do not get police help
How can I track her position
Or it back together

Answer (score 1):

If you had Find My iPhone enabled, then the thief would have needed to know your Apple ID login details to be able to remove it from iCloud.

If you didn't, all they had to do was wipe it & it's gone.